# SQL Pivot Column that has multiple values for same column

Tags: sql, pivot

Trying to pivot table results that may have multiple rows with the same value
I have data that looks like this so far.

```
Nbr      Person     Test

33      Barry.      Prim
33      Brian       Sup
33      Burke RT    1st
33      Ray         Add
33      Jake        Add
33      Smith       Add
```

I'm trying to pivot it so that it looks like this:

```
Nbr   Prim    Sup     1st       Add   Add2       Add3

33   Barry   Brian   Burke      Ray   Jake       Smith
```

This is what I have so far with a normal pivot but it doesn't work to grab all the ones with the same value in the Test Column

```
CREATE TABLE #testTbl(nbr int,name varchar(20),test VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #testTbl
SELECT '33','Barry','Prim'
UNION
SELECT '33','Brian','Sup'
UNION
SELECT '33','Burke','1st'
UNION
SELECT '33','Ray','Add'
UNION
SELECT '33','jake','Add'
UNION
SELECT '33','Smith','Add'


select * from (
Select * 
from #testTbl
) as x
 pivot(
 max(name) for test in ([prim],[sup],[1st],[add])
)
as pivot1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. If its not possible to have the columns output as Add Add2 and Add3 thats fine. Whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by modifying the `test` value using window functions:

```
select *
from (Select tt.name,
             (test + (case when count(*) over (partition by test) = 1
                           then ''
                           else cast(row_number() over (partition by test order by (select null)) as varchar(255))
                      end)) as test
      from testTbl tt
     ) as x
pivot(
 max(name) for test in ([prim], [sup], [1st], [Add1], [Add2], [Add3])
) as pivot1
```

A SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19918/9).

Comment: Gordon - Thanks! You beat me to my own answer as I was narrowing in on this solution too but I was just about to google how to do the pivot when I don't know exactly how many Add's there will be. It could be Add1 Add2 Add3....

Comment: @Jt2ouan . . . Then you need a dynamic pivot.  Google "dynamic pivot" along with your database name.

Comment: Yup found that too. I always forget pivot techniques when I don't pivot too often.